# From where does the @login_manager.user_loader get the user id?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

The following flask function with its decorator apparently loads a given user_id into the flask_session.

I was wondering from where does this function get the user_id? Is it from the `login_user(email, '....')` method or UserMixin class? I read somewhere that the `login_user()` calls the `get_id()` or `is_active` from the UserMixin. Is this correct?

I'd also like to know how these three, (decorator, login_user, UserMixin) are related to each other.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```

Answer (score 1):

> This callback is used to reload the user object from the user ID stored in the session.

I find above sentence from documentation of [`Flask-Login`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

You're misunderstanding the function of `load_user(user_id)`. It load user object by user id from session instead of load a given user id into the session.

The `load_user(user_id)` get user id from session instead of `login_user` or `UserMixin`.

After browse the source code of `Flask-Login`, The `login_user` function only call the `is_active` from `UserMixin`.

About the relation between the decorator, `login_user` and `UserMixin`,

At first, You should define a `User` data model inherit from `db.Model`(from Flask-SQLAlchemy) and `UserMixin`;

And then use the `login_manager.user_loader` decorator to register the callback function for reloading a user from the session which will used to check if the user have logined;

At last, Once a user has authenticated, you log them in with the login_user function which insert user id into the session.

I recommend you use [`Flask-Security`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/) to replace  `Flask-Login`.

Comment: thank you stamaimer , it was helpful to some extent. but if @lm.load_user loads id from the session, from where does the session get the id ?

Comment: I have said in the last. When you login user use `login_user` function. You can check the source code of [`login_user`](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/flask_login/utils.py#L127) in Flask-Login.